# The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, monodevelop

I'm wading through compiling and install MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 13.10.

It's requiring so many manual compilation of other dependencies, which have found some information online to solve.

Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this one:

```
The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'
```

`./configure` goes fine, but make gives me the above message, along with the following:

```
mkdir -p build/
make DEBUG_BeforeBuild
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/leon/dev/monodevelop/extras/JavaBinding'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/leon/dev/monodevelop/extras/JavaBinding'
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../../local-config:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH dmcs -noconfig -codepage:utf8 -warn:4 -optimize- -debug -define:DEBUG -out:build/JavaBinding.dll -target:library './AssemblyInfo.cs' './gtk-gui/generated.cs' './gtk-gui/JavaBinding.CodeGenerationPanelWidget.cs' './gtk-gui/JavaBinding.GlobalOptionsPanelWidget.cs' './Gui/GlobalOptionsPanel.cs' './Gui/ProjectConfigurationPropertyPanel.cs' './IKVMCompilerManager.cs' './JavaCompiler.cs' './JavaLanguageBinding.cs' './Project/JavaCompilerParameters.cs'  '-resource:./gtk-gui/gui.stetic' '-resource:./icons/Java.FileIcon' '-resource:./icons/java-16.png' '-resource:./icons/java-22.png' '-resource:./icons/java-icon-32.png' '-resource:./JavaBinding.addin.xml' '-resource:./md1format.xml' '-resource:./templates/EmptyJavaFile.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/EmptyJavaProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/IkvmConsoleApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/IkvmGladeApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/IkvmGnomeApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/IkvmGtkApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/IkvmLibraryProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaApplet.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaApplication.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaConsoleApplicationProject.xpt.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaDialog.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaFrame.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaOKDialog.xft.xml' '-resource:./templates/JavaPanel.xft.xml'    -r:Mono.Posix   -pkg:glade-sharp-2.0   -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0   -pkg:mono-addins   -pkg:monodevelop    -r:System    -r:System.Drawing    -r:System.Xml  
./JavaLanguageBinding.cs(31,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./JavaLanguageBinding.cs(32,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./JavaLanguageBinding.cs(34,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./JavaLanguageBinding.cs(109,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IParser' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./JavaLanguageBinding.cs(113,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IRefactorer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 5 error(s), 0 warnings
make[2]: *** [build/JavaBinding.dll] Error 1
```

How do I get these last blocking items installed in order to build successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "extras/JavaBinding" and "extras/ValaBinding" via './configure --select'. They do not work.